# How can I call my UnitOfWork from a Web Service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap

I have an assignment from where I have to create 4 Web Services via 4 different projects. I am using the Northwind database. I have created a 5th project that is just a database handler. I am using Entity Frame Works, Repositories and UnitOfWork to retrieve data from the database. This way I figured the 4 web services could each instantiate UnitOfWork and retrieve the data needed.

The problem is I cannot instantiate UnitOfWork because it is another project, and this web service will not allow me to make any references. When I right click to make a reference I get the following error "A reference to 'DBHandler' could not be added. A project must build to a 'dll' extension in order to be referenced". Now I have googled this phrase and I see other questions regarding it, but not any that relates to what I am working on.

I simply have no clue how I am supposed to call the UnitOfWork class so I can get my data from the database. How can I call my UnitOfWork from a Web Service?

Comment: Why would you create 4 web services in 4 different projects?  I would just do File -> New Project -> MVC project (with Web API).  Afterwards, I would create 4 WEB API CONTROLLERS each representing a different web service.  As for EF, I would use an Inversion of Control (IOC) container, like Unity or Ninject, to manage the creation and destruction of the EF context on each request since the context is not thread safe.  I assume that's why your using a UnitOfWork, but  I would look for an example that using Unity or Ninject and a PerRequestLifetimeManager to manage the EF context.

Comment: Because my assignment is the following

"Based on the NorthWind database you should create 4 services:
1. Inventory Service (Products & Suppliers)
2. CRM Service (Customers)
3. HR Service (Employees)
4. Purchase Order Service
§ All services must be in their own application (i.e. they
do not share data)
§ Each of the supporting services (1-3) must define the services needed by the Purchase Order Service
§ You must implement a Service Façade on the inventory
service"

It's a school project. But it being in 4 different projects is not the problem. The project handling the DB is.

Comment: You have to either put your UOW in a library project, which compiles to a dll,  and import an existing project into the other 4 OR compile the UOW library project and copy the dll into a folder in each project and import the compile dll into the projects. In the real world, most common dlls would be distributed via a local Nuget server so that the 4 separate projects are aware of any changes.